# ionic 2: ionic resources --icon not update my ionic logo app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I'm trying to update my ionic 2 app logo with the command

> ionic resources --icon

I did a new logo and it i see it create the logo in other sizes after this command but when i move the apk app to my phone, it still the default logo.

Comment: Remove your platform and add it again.

Comment: i did it and still not change the logo.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

> ionic platform rm android
>
> ionic platform add android@6.1.0

Comment: It was a bug and they fixed it on that version [link](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/11/07/android-release.html). but why ionic do not use the last version of cordova?